# Python Regex stop at '|' character

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a URL in a Dokuwiki using python regex. Dokuwikis format URLs like this:

```
[['insert URL'|Name of External Link]]
```

I need to design a python regex that captures the URL but stops at `'|'`

I could try and type out every non-alphanumeric character besides `'|'`
(something like this: `(https?://[\w|\.|\-|\?|\/|\=|\+|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|^|&]*) )`

However that sounds really tedious and I might miss one.

Thoughts?

Comment: `[^\|]+` reads, anything but "|"

Comment: in addition to that, links don't have whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative character sets, or `[^things to not match]`.

In this case, you want to not match `|`, so you would have `[^|]`.

```
import re

bool(re.match("[^|]", "a"))
#>>> True

bool(re.match("[^|]", "|"))
#>>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

You expect any character that's not | followed by a | and some other characters that are not ], everything enclosed within double square brackets. This translates to:

```
pattern = re.compile('\[\[([^\|]+)\|([^/]]+)\]\]')
print pattern.match("[[http://bla.org/path/to/page|Name of External Link]]").groups()
```

This would print:

```
('http://bla.org/path/to/page', 'Name of External Link')
```

If you don't need the name of the link you can just remove the parenthesis around the second group. More on regular expressions in Python [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Clsoe but not working. The proper regex is: `re.compile('\[\[([^|]+)\|([^]]+)\]\]')`. You've got extra chars like a backslash and a slash in your regex that make it fail.